# Jenkins says "No tests found" when "Notify Test summary" is enabled. (For slack notifications)

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins, pytest, slack

I have installed jenkins plugin and print the output to slack.

My tests runs with Pytest and the output is as below. (Taken from Jenkins console).

```
[Slack Notifications] found #13 as previous completed, non-aborted build
[Slack Notifications] will send OnSuccessNotification because build matches and user preferences allow it
Finished: SUCCESS
```

But In my actual slack notification it says:

```
XXX>>XXX : #14 Success after 45 sec (Open)
No Tests found.
```

Why does it say "No Tests found". How to get 23 Passed, 2 Warnings printed in this case.

Answer (score 0):

@Rekha, after facing the same problem, I've found out that it seems you can only add the test summery when not using custom messages. Unfortunately, the issue on github was closed:

https://github.com/jenkinsci/slack-plugin/issues/313

*Edit:* Turning off the custom messages didn't work for me. The slack notification still says "No Tests found."